# Can we start / stop all channel adapters with a single control bus message?

Tags: spring-integration

I know we can start / stop channel adapters by sending a control bus message like: @adapterid.start(). 
But can we do that for all adapters we have with a single message?
like: @allAdapters.start() ? 
In my system I have around 20 inbound adapters and handling them one by one is not a flexible solution.

Thanks,

Ferenc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember as I did that with inline Groovy script:

```
<service-activator>
   <groovy:script>
          ['foo1', 'foo2'].each {
                this."$it".start()
          }
   </groovy:script>
</service-activator>
```

Or you can do that with some custom Java component, which is injected with all desired components and its `start()` just iterates over them and calls their `start()` by simple control-bus command for your container bean.

Comment: Ok. Currently I'm doing that, but this seems like hacking.So If I understand you correctly there is no built-in solution for handling this problem. You have to send messages one by one.

Comment: Right. It is really a specific of your app. And don't forget the one of Spring Integration purposes to provide the `loosely-coupling` principle implementation. It really doesn't sound good to `start/stop` all adapters at once as a Framework feature.

Comment: There could be a  InboundChannelRegistry where all channel adapters should be registered at startup dinamically. Then you can send a message to the registry to stop / start all registered adapter. This does not harm the "loosely-coupling" principle. I think.

Comment: There are several `@ManagedOperation`s on the `IntegrationMBeanExporter` - `stopActiveChannels()`, `stopMessageSources()` and `stopInboundMessageProducers()`. These are invoked by the over-arching `stopActiveComponents()` operation. The last two would do what you want for stop, but there is no way to start them because this was really intended for orderly shutdown before closing the application context. Since the `IMBE` already has the "registry" you are talking about, we could relatively easily add start support. Feel free to open a [JIRA new feature](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).